# Wordpress Navigation Walker change ul, li for div and anchor tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to create a custom markup for my WordPress menu, when I add a menu in WordPress, the HTML that shows is as follows:

```html
<div class="menu-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-13">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14">
            <a href="#">Another Sample</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-15">
            <a href="#">Sample Page</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-22">
                    <a href="#">Hello world!</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to change the code so that it will display using the anchor and div tags instead of ul and li. This is to work with the Bulma framework.

Normal link code:

```html
<a class="navbar-item" href="#">Home</a>
```

Dropdown link code:

```html
<div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
    <a class="navbar-link" href="#">Sample Page</a>
    <div class="navbar-dropdown">
        <a class="navbar-item" href="#">Sample Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another reason I am trying to do this is to remove all of the unnecessary class and id attributes that WordPress automatically adds.

Is this possible with WordPress by using a walker?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, you can use

https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker (most common)

You can also check

1) https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navlist-walker
2) https://github.com/jprieton/wp-bootstrap4-navwalker
3) https://github.com/dupkey/bs4navwalker